# Problems with React Native and Android Studio after the latter updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, android-studio-3.6

After Android Studio automatically updating to 3.6, i've been getting this error message:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800    throw err;  
  ^Error: Cannot find module '/Users/aleksandrskryl/Desktop/EngApp/android/undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (9 s 863 ms)
```

What I've tried to do thus far to solve this problem:

- Deleting all packages (`node_modules`) and reinstalling them from both `package.json` and manually via `npm`
- Downloading cli module (`@react-native-community/cli-platform-android`) (but it led to new problems)
- Deleting files with `.iml` extension and `.idea` folder
- Installing older version of Android Studio (3.5.3)

Comment: pls upload IDE log